# How to prevent git receive

Tags: git

I have one post-receive hook which will take one minute to execute. While executing this hook no one else should be able to push.

Is there any way I can do this? or How do I configure git (in remote repository) so that it doesn't allow to push from client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do it yourself: Create a lockfile in your post-receive hook and delete it once it’s done. Add a [pre-receive hook](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html) that blocks if that file exists.

This will allow race conditions, though. If two clients start pushing at the same time, they will both reach the post-receive hook. Why exactly do you need this exclusive access?

Comment: I prefer that solution actually: you can set an explicit error message in the pre-receive hook. +1

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a [`git config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) to deny *all* push.

That leaves you with tricks to "break" the access mechanism:

- If your users are accessing to your git repos through ssh, move the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys temporarily.
- If your user uses https addresses, move the `<git>/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend` executable used for those transactions.

This isn't a pretty solution, as in both cases, it will result in error messages in the client side, but you won't get any push while those files are moved.